# What is the type of scroll event in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

```
<div (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
```

```
onScroll(event: any) {
   const value= event.target;
  }
```

Here instead of type "any" ,I need to put the type of the event. Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 6):

It would be `Event` as a type.

```js
onScroll(event: Event) {
   const value= event.target;
  }
```

Fired at the Document or element when the viewport or element is scrolled, respectively.
https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#event-summary

An event can be triggered by the user action e.g. clicking the mouse button or tapping keyboard, or generated by APIs to represent the progress of an asynchronous task.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to find out ([not using the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll_event)) would be to print the input:

```
 onScroll(event: any): void {
    console.log(event);
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Event` but if you are sure your target is `HTMLElement` you can use it like this:

`event: Event & { target: HTMLElement}`

```
onScroll(event: Event & { target: HTMLElement}) {
   ...
}
```