# Angular - What is the type for @HostListener window:scroll event

Tags: angular, typescript

Here I'm getting some errors like:

- 'e.target' is possibly 'null'.
- Property 'scrollingElement' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

What should be the type for the event param on the onWindowScroll function?

```
import { Component, ElementRef, HostListener, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-layout-topbar',
  templateUrl: './topbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./topbar.component.scss'],
})
export class TopbarComponent {
  @ViewChild('topbar') topbar?: ElementRef;

  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  onWindowScroll(e: Event) {
    if (!this.topbar) return;
    if (e.target.scrollingElement.scrollTop > 500) {
      this.topbar.nativeElement.classList.add('sticky-topbar');
      this.topbar.nativeElement.classList.remove('hide-topbar');
    } else if (e.target.scrollingElement.scrollTop > 10) {
      this.topbar.nativeElement.classList.add('hide-topbar');
    } else {
      this.topbar.nativeElement.classList.remove('sticky-topbar');
      this.topbar.nativeElement.classList.remove('hide-topbar');
    }
  }
}
```

After some research, I saw people talking about the type Event. But it seems that this is the wrong type. Ex: [What is the type of scroll event in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70874413/what-is-the-type-of-scroll-event-in-angular)

Comment: The type for the `event` parameter in the `onWindowScroll` function should be `UIEvent`. This is because scroll events are instances of `UIEvent` in the browser environment

Comment: you can use `if(event.target instanceof  HTMLElement)` then its treated like a html element inside the `if` block, then you should have access to the elements properties without casting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a generic `Event` as stated here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scrollend_event#event_type

Answer (score 1):

There is no special type for a scroll event.

When in doubt, use the native `addEventListener` to see the inferred type for `event`.

For example :

```
addEventListener("click", (event) => {});
```

`event` is inferred as `MouseEvent`

For the scroll

```
addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {});
```

`event` is a bare `Event`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYExFEDcFMDsBcAyBLAzvO0BOAKARAMYA2yBA1ngDQAEO0MCAlNQLwB81A3gL6MDc1AFDURoseImiA9FOoA9APyDBoCAyRoMsbPlQEsAeyJEqtenHjN2XXgOGSHDmSMVA)

Answer (score 0):

The type of the event is not the problem, because the `scroll` event only has the basic type `Event`.

`event.target` is of type `EventTarget | null`, which means that in order to access `target` you'll need to first check if it's `null`:

```
if(event.target === null) return;
```

After that you will have to cast `event.target` to a different type as [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget)
only defines 3 methods that all elements have in common.

In your case, `target` is the `Document` itself, so you can access `scrollingElement` by doing

```
(e.target as Document).scrollingElement.scrollTop > 500
```